# Filter on a field with choices

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have this field:

```
operation = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=OPERATIONS)
```

Having this filter works:

```
class OperationFilter(django_filters.Filter):

    def filter(self, qs, value):
        try:
            qs = qs.filter(operation=value.upper())
        except:
            pass
        return qs
```

With url:

```
/api/v1/operation/?operation=CREATE
```

But having the default filter (without an extra `OperationFilter`) fails with:

```
{
    "operation": [
        "Select a valid choice. %(value)s is not one of the available choices."
    ]
}
```

Why is a filter on a field with choices failing?

For other, non-choice fields, default filters are working fine:

```
/api/v1/operation/?recipient=recipient-19
```

### EDIT

The `OPERATIONS`:

```
from enum import Enum

def enum_as_choices(enum_class):
    """From an enum class, generate choices for a django field"""
    return ((entry, entry.value) for entry in enum_class)

class OperationType(Enum):
    CREATE = 'CREATE'
    STATUS = 'STATUS'
    EXPAND = 'EXPAND'
    DELETE = 'DELETE'

OPERATIONS = enum_as_choices(OperationType)
```

Comment: Do your `OPERATIONS` choices include a blank or default choice?

Comment: @DanielH., no, no blank choice. The choices are derived from an `Enum`

Comment: Please include how you defined your `Enum` in the post

Comment: please show OPERATIONS variable.

Comment: Are you using DRF?

Comment: @DanielH. added

Comment: @SergeyMiletskiy added

Comment: @angoru yes (also, it is tagged as drf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choices you written would be converted to this pythonic representation:

```
(
    ('OperationType.CREATE', 'CREATE'), 
    ('OperationType.STATUS', 'STATUS'), 
    ('OperationType.EXPAND', 'EXPAND'), 
    ('OperationType.DELETE', 'DELETE')
)
```

As you can see the actual values stored in your operation field (in DB) are `'OperationType.CREATE'`, etc. 
So you should change your choices to normal constant choices or you should filter by something like `'OperationType.CREATE'` which is not a good option IMO.

also you can change your `enum_as_choices` method like this:

```
def enum_as_choices(enum_class):
    """From an enum class, generate choices for a django field"""
    return ((entry.name, entry.value) for entry in enum_class)
```

Comment: I agree with you, I think better to use `tuple()` or `list()` in the function                                                              `return tuple((entry.name, entry.value) for entry in enum_class)`

Comment: Actually, not `('OperationType.CREATE', 'CREATE')` but `(OperationType.CREATE, 'CREATE')`. Using the name solves the problem, as in `('CREATE', 'CREATE')`. Your corrected `enum_as_choices` does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: You are right about the type, but the actual data saved in the db is the str() of your enum fields and I mentioned it.

Answer (score 2):

You are using [django_filters](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter) package, I suggest reading docs, since you already have support for this

https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#choicefilter

Just point out your `choices` to the value suggested by the other answers (or check the example in docs)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a blank/default choice in your `OPERATIONS`. To do so, add something like this:

```
OPERATIONS = (
    ('', 'NONE'),
    # the rest of your choices here...
)
```

But you would also need to update your model to be:

```
operation = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=OPERATIONS, default='NONE')
```

Comment: The problem is not related to the default choice.